# Using the Onboard VGA output and not using the PCIe nvidia card

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display

I have installed a `nVidia Geforce 780` card on my desktop. My motherboard has a onboard display port too. My Bios has the following choices of display

- Auto, CPU Graphics, PCIe, PCIx.
- Multiple Monitors Enabled/Disable

When I choose `CPU Graphics` and `Disable` the `Multiple Monitors` setting in the BIOS, the desktop boots using the Onboard graphics port. But as soon as ubuntu X loads it switches to the Nvidia card. How do I fix this ?

I tried using `nvidia-settings` from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30073/using-the-onboard-vga-output-with-a-pcie-video-card-both-nvidia), but that has only choice of Monitors. All other posts talk about BIOS settings, but I think its a `X` issue and not a BIOS issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, I followed the steps on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9IFWXehues) video. Basically `Additional Drivers`, select the latest Nvidia driver and hit Apply. Open `Nvidia XServer Settings` and choose `PRIME profiles`, select `Intel graphics card`. Fixed.